# Tailwind / NativeWind React Native / Expo default fontFamily does not apply

Tags: react-native, expo, tailwind-css

I'm working on an Expo App and currently use nativewind 2.0.10 as well as tailwindcss 3.1.8. Everything works fine besides the following setup.

**Problem description:**
I want to use `OpenSans` as the default `fontFamily`. Though the font does not get applied on `Text` components by default.

**My Setup:**

```
// tailwind.config.js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

module.exports = {
  content: ['./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        'sans': ['OpenSans'],
        'sans-light': ['OpenSansLight'],
        'sans-bold': ['OpenSansBold']
      },
  },
  plugins: []
}
```

```
// App.js
const App = () => {

const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'OpenSans': require('fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'),
    'OpenSansLight': require('fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Light.ttf'),
    'OpenSansSemiBold': require('fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf'),
    'OpenSansBold': require('fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Bold.ttf'),
    'OpenSansExtraBold': require('fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf'),
    'OpenSansItalic': require('fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Italic.ttf')
  })

return !fontsLoaded ? null : <Text>Test Open Sans</Text>
}
```

**Current behaviour:**
I can confirm that the fonts are loaded and are even accessible via tailwind. Eg, if I write the the return statement of `App.js` as any of the following, it applies `OpenSans` as font correctly:

```
return <Text className="font-[OpenSans]">Test Open Sans</Text>
return <Text className="font-sans">Test Open Sans</Text>

return <Text style={{fontFamily: "OpenSans"}}>Test Open Sans</Text>
```

**My Question:**
It would be great if `OpenSans` gets applied to `Text` components by default and I do not have to call it explicitly like in the first 2 examples from above. But is this even possible? I'm confused since tailwind can make use of the additionally loaded fonts, it just does not apply them as default `fontFamily`.

Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: Here is a minimal reproduction of the behaviour for anyone interested https://github.com/marklawlor/nativewind/issues/387

Answer (score 2):

Try to not extend the theme but override it:

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      sans: ['"OpenSans"']
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: That had no effect unfortunately

Comment: You should create your `text` component to wrap this and apply your `className`. It's strange behavior tho.

Comment: Yes, that's probably the best solution for now. If I have time, I'll check the developer menu for what style does get applied in the non functional approach right now and also post the issue on the github repo.